# Creating a RTM doc using Protractor Tests

Tags: protractor, requirements-validation

I would like suggestions for how people create RTM documents when creating automated test cases using Protractor/Jasmine. We have our suites set up based on logical sections of the application, not by requirement/user story. What is the best approach for 'tagging' individual test cases (within suites or across suites) to be linked and ran to a particular user story/requirement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Generally I try and create end-to-end workflows for major functionality.
I group tests by file.
One approach I also use is to use tags for happy, sad and options workflows.

- Happy is being the quick, all correct input route
- Sad is trying to generate as many errors as possible
- Options means adding other stuff. Will depend on the application and data.

I focus on making the descriptions and structure most useful and detailed in the end tool. i.e. Jasmine